# .NET XmlDocument: Including default namespace prefixes in OuterXml

Tags: .net, xml, namespaces

I have an XmlDocument object that contains the following XML:

```
<root>
   <childlist xmlns:pre="mydomain.com">
     <pre:child someattribute="value" />
  </childlist>
</root>
```

The client application, which receives the XML document as a string, requires that the  element have the "pre:" prefix.

My problem is that, when I get the XML text from the XmlDocument using the .OuterXml method, the prefix is removed:

```
<root>
  <childlist xmlns:pre="mydomain.com">
    <child someattribute="value" />  <!--where's the prefix?-->
  </childlist>
</root>
```

I understand that, technically, the prefix is unnecessary for the default namespace, but, again, the client that receives this XML won't work without the prefix.

When I inspect the  node using the debugger, the .Name property is "pre:child". So the XmlDocument object is storing the prefix, it just doesn't come out in .OuterXml.

Is there any way to serialize the XmlDocument object and include the element name prefixes?

I've played with a couple of approaches that use the XmlSerializer and XmlTextWriter objects, but I get the same results. Perhaps there's a property on the XmlDocument, XmlSerializer, or XmlTextWriter that would specify that I want the default namespace prefixes to be included in the output?

(Incidentally, if you just load the above XML into the XmlDocument object using .LoadXml(), the prefixes will appear in the .OuterXml. They only disappear if you build the document using .AppendNode().)

Comment: Can you share the actual code that generate the XML document before you get `.OuterXml` property?

Answer (score 0):

Kind of found an answer:

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/568487-inserting-xml-node-maintaining-prefix

It's not perfect--it assumes that the element that supplies the NamespacedURI also needs the prefix. But it's a workable start.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, the key seemed to be adding an XmlNode as NodeType Element.  Versus directly adding as XmlElement.

Please note, the "urn:something:mapper:somethingelse:commontypes" is going to come from the names space specified in your XML document.

```
        XmlNodeList xNodSIDetails = xDoc.GetElementsByTagName("pt:SIDetails");
        // Select the parent node where you want to add the element
        XmlNode xSID = xNodSIDetails[0];
        // Select the peer node that you want to insert the element after.
        XmlNode xLotNum = xNodSIDetails[0].ChildNodes[3];
        // Create the node, of the type Element, with the name you want including the prefix and the namespace URI.
        XmlNode xn = xDoc.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element,"cmn:ExpirationDate", "urn:something:mapper:somethingelse:commontypes"); 
        //  Assign the Node the inner text value.
        xn.InnerText = "1999-03-24";
        //  Insert the node after the one you previous chose for this to follow.
        xSID.InsertAfter(xn, xLotNum);
```